# Expanding a Map<String,String> to Map<String,Map> based on the key

Tags: java, maps

If I have a map like:

```
Map.of("key1", "value1",
       "key2.subkey1", "subvalue1",
       "key2.subkey2", "subvalue2",
       "key2.subkey3.subsubkey", "subsubvalue");
```

Then I would like to convert it to a map of (possibly) maps like this:

```
Map.of("key1", "value1",
       "key2", Map.of("subkey1", "subvalue1",
                      "subkey2", "subvalue2",
                      "subkey3", Map.of("subsubkey", "subsubvalue)));
```

I figure I need to split the keys like so:

```
entry.getKey().split("\\.", 2);
```

But I cant figure out what to do after that.

Comment: like this? `for (String key : map.keySet()) { /*create a new map with result of map.get(key); */ }` and add to the new map-signature. It goes without saying - you can't put booleans into <string> or doubles into <int>. You need to create a new map-signature and store the results there.

Comment: You can't have `String` and `Map` as a value type in the same map unless you have `Object` as your value type.

Comment: @Joel: Not every `key` will need its own map.

Comment: @ScottHunter Sure, i mean, it's just a suggestion to get him started. Hence why I wrote that he should create a new map with the results of map.get(key);. He has to detect whether or not it is supposed to be a new map or not, but he still needs to store the results in the appropriate map-signature. As M.S wrote - Object is probably his best bet. Tho, This entire question is structurally flawed in many ways. Resort to JSON if this is actually a desirable data-structure. and then convert it to classes at will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use recursion in these cases (cascaded keys):

```java
public static Map<String, Object> covert(Map<String, String> map) {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    map.forEach((key, value) -> parseAndPut(result, key, value));
    return result;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static void parseAndPut(Map<String, Object> map, String key, String value) {
    String[] keys = key.split("\\.");
    if (keys.length == 1) {
        map.put(key, value);
    } else if (keys.length > 1) {
        String subKey = keys[0];
        Map<String, Object> valueMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.computeIfAbsent(subKey, s -> new HashMap<>());
        int beginIndex = key.indexOf(subKey) + subKey.length() + 1;
        parseAndPut(valueMap, key.substring(beginIndex), value);
    }
}
```

Output for your input data:

```
{key1=value1, key2={subkey1=subvalue1, subkey2=subvalue2, subkey3={subsubkey=subsubvalue}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make this method which does what I want, but it doesn't look very pretty :(

```
private Map<String, Object> expandMap(Map<String, String> oldMap) {
    HashMap<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    oldMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        String[] keys = key.split("\\.", 2);
        if (keys.length == 1) {
            newMap.put(keys[0], value);
        } else {
            newMap.merge(keys[0], expandMap(Map.of(keys[1], value)), (obj1, obj2) -> {
                if (obj1 instanceof Map && obj2 instanceof Map) {
                    Map<String, Object> map1 = (Map<String, Object>) obj1;
                    Map<String, Object> map2 = (Map<String, Object>) obj2;
                    return Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream()).collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
                }
                return null;
            });
        }
    });
    return newMap;
}
```

You are welcome to share your thoughts.